# Kernel panic during work on kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, arm, kernel, ubifs

i have the following issue. I'm working w/ some Linux-based embedded system. 
i create an image w/ my linux, load it to device and run. Everything was pretty cool till i added some 3rd-party modules. After this the loading was failed w/ the following stack:

```
 lib80211: common routines for IEEE802.11 drivers
 [    2.760000] UBIFS: parse sync
 [    2.770000] UBIFS error (pid 1): ubifs_read_node: bad node type (0 but expected 6)
 [    2.780000] UBIFS error (pid 1): ubifs_read_node: bad node at LEB 0:0
 [    2.810000] List of all partitions:
 [    2.810000] 1f00            1024 mtdblock0 (driver?)
 [    2.810000] 1f01            1024 mtdblock1 (driver?)
 [    2.820000] 1f02            1024 mtdblock2 (driver?)
 [    2.820000] 1f03            1024 mtdblock3 (driver?)
 [    2.830000] 1f04           40960 mtdblock4 (driver?)
 [    2.830000] 1f05           38656 mtdblock5 (driver?)
 [    2.840000] 1f06           40960 mtdblock6 (driver?)
 [    2.840000] 1f07           38656 mtdblock7 (driver?)
 [    2.850000] 1f08           40960 mtdblock8 (driver?)
 [    2.850000] 1f09            1024 mtdblock9 (driver?)
 [    2.860000] 1f0a            1024 mtdblock10 (driver?)
 [    2.860000] No filesystem could mount root, tried:  ubifs
 [    2.870000] Kernel panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,255)
 [    2.880000] [<c0054bdc>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe4) from [<c033b1f8>] (panic+0x68/0x188)
 [    2.890000] [<c033b1f8>] (panic+0x68/0x188) from [<c000920c>] (mount_block_root+0x238/0x288)
 [    2.890000] [<c000920c>] (mount_block_root+0x238/0x288) from     [<c0009430>] (prepare_namespace+0x88/0x1c0)
 [    2.900000] [<c0009430>] (prepare_namespace+0x88/0x1c0) from [<c0008e80>] (kernel_init+0x1c8/0x218)
 [    2.910000] [<c0008e80>] (kernel_init+0x1c8/0x218) from [<c004fbb8>]  (kernel_thread_exit+0x0/0x8)
 [    2.920000] CPU0: stopping
 [    2.920000] [<c0054bdc>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0xe4) from [<c004e2cc>] (do_IPI+0xd8/0x150)
 [    2.920000] [<c004e2cc>] (do_IPI+0xd8/0x150) from [<c0402c88>] (__irq_svc+0x48/0xe8)
 [    2.920000] Exception stack(0xc043ff78 to 0xc043ffc0)
 [    2.920000] ff60:                                                       c044e5ac 00000000
 [    2.920000] ff80: c043ffc0 00000000 c043e000 c044ab38 c04600a8 c044ab30 000266b4 413fc090
 [    2.920000] ffa0: 0000001f 00000000 c04cbc58 c043ffc0 c004fc10 c004fc14 60000013 ffffffff
 [    2.920000] [<c0402c88>] (__irq_svc+0x48/0xe8) from [<c004fc14>] (default_idle+0x24/0x28)
 [    2.920000] [<c004fc14>] (default_idle+0x24/0x28) from [<c004fd7c>] (cpu_idle+0x40/0x94)
 [    2.920000] [<c004fd7c>] (cpu_idle+0x40/0x94) from [<c0008c5c>] (start_kernel+0x318/0x374)
 [    2.920000] [<c0008c5c>] (start_kernel+0x318/0x374) from [<00008084>] (0x8084)
```

i'm not sure that problem is w/ lack of room on device's flash memory. But anyway i can't figure out what can be the reason of this failure.

What is the reason of this failure can b?

The 'uname -r' returns the following:

```
2.6.36.4brcmarm
```

Let me know if anything else is needed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is wirtten: Unable to mount root fs ... i guess that is the reason

Comment: Why are you using kernel 2.6.36 instead of a recent version?

Comment: CL, unfortunately this is a legacy project. not the choice of mine(

Comment: Alex, it is. But i can't find out what is the reason of it. The third-party module i included doesn't have to make the error like this. That is the problem actually..

Comment: @user1053031 probably you have changed a ubifs driver and now layout of your partition and driver are in inconsistent state. Be sure that your root partition actually contains ubifs

Comment: Alex, how can i verify this?

Comment: Post your kernel config (part related to ubifs) and kernel cmd line also all steps were done before crash i.e. what have you updated in what sequence which files were affected (if you believe update is the reason of crash)

Comment: Is it possible that your kernel image has exceeded a partition size and you have over-wrote the UBI/UbiFS image when you flashed it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it seems issue was fixed when i increased the size of file-system (-c parameter value during mkfs.ubifs call). Thanks for all help and suggestions!